# Prevent direct access to views/routes in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This might be a silly question but I am just learning Laravel.

I have a form in Laravel which upon submits (NON AJAX) it redirects to a thanks page.

How can I restrict any user to access the route/view directly via the browser?

What I am trying to prevent is for example a user typing http://mywebsite.com/thanks and receiving the blade view thanks.blade.php

Thanks in advanced

Comment: The simplest  way would be to do a `Session::flash('something')` on the `submit` page,  check if it exists in the `thanks` page, if it doesn't redirect to whatever, if it does, then carry on.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you *need* to restrict people from visiting the "thanks" page (i.e. does it expose some information that users shouldn't see without submitting the form)? If there's no links to it, I wouldn't worry too much about it, but if you really need to, you could set a session variable when they submit, and then add middleware to the 'thanks' page which requires that session variable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!!! that did the trick!!

Comment: To be clear, this should be done in the controller or as middleware on the route.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help!! It is very appreciated especially when I am new to Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following Andrew's advice, setting a flash session variable and checking if exist in the view.

Thanks